# ubuntu not booting!

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows

Well thanks a lot everybody for help. I played around with my computer and installed Ubuntu in UEFI. I have never seen such an energetic forum. But now, there is another problem. Sorry :P

Now in my boot menu I have 3 options:

1. Windows boot manager
2. Linus something. I figured out, it only appeared if when my bootable usb was plugged.
3. ubuntu

Well, a good new before, i successfully installed ubuntu and it asked me to reboot. When I did so and clicked on the 3rd option, it booted into windows.

When i clicked 2 and tried to use try without installing, it says "Unable to find a medium containing live file system"

What should i do?

Thanks in advance and sorry for bothering u guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) is my "go to" for creating live drives. After creating a live drive, plug it in and re-order your boot order to boot from it. Note that some motherboards have increase security in their UEFI to prevent this and require some extra work-arounds. These work-arounds are usually motherboard specific so you'll have to look around elsewhere. From there, you should be able to install Ubuntu to the empty partition you made earlier, and install GRUB at the same time, which will be your new boot loader with both Windows and Ubuntu available.

Be sure to re-partition your hard drive from within Windows before booting from the live drive. Although you can re-partition during the Ubuntu installation, Windows offers a nice GUI that would be more new person friendly.

Alternatively, if you are unfamiliar with Linux and are concerned about "breaking" your system, perhaps consider virtualizing Ubuntu in a [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) with either VMware Player or VirtualBox. Long story short, it would run Ubuntu within your Windows rather than beside it, and will allow you  to create "check points" that you can revert to at any time and will leave your Windows partition safe.

Comment: I used rufus to create live drive. In my boot order, USB is on the top. The fact is that when I switch to legacy mode, I see the installer and can try ubuntu as well but, not in UEFI. I read that both operating systems should have the same bios settings.

Comment: One more question, I have 500+gb of unformatted space. Do I still need to create partitions and shrink the C: drive?

Comment: I'm not sure about your first comment, about both OSs using the same settings. To answer your second comment though, no. I'm assuming you have one partition formatted and containing your Windows install, you should be able to format the 500 GB partition and install Ubuntu to it during the Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/), it will allow you to create a bootable Linux USB from within Windows and works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Rawrite32](https://www.netbsd.org/~martin/rawrite32/download.html) to create a bootable usb drive. It's very easy to use and can be run within Windows.